# model.predict(dataset) give me "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

Now I'm editing Movie Reviews with bert-for-tf2 on TPU.ipynb to run Korean samples.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BeG1n9IJmoxBZ2FicKKqWTdQ11jfYxlC?usp=sharing

To test the trained model with sample sentence, I use model.predict() function.

I got the error message as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in catch_stop_iteration(self)
   1151             "{} batches). You may need to use the repeat() function "
   1152             "when building your dataset.".format(total_epochs *
-> 1153                                                  self._inferred_steps))
   1154 
   1155   def steps(self):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I just changed the original code to convert sentence into batched dataset.

My code are as follows

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences


def sentence_tfrecord_to_dataset(filenames):
  ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
  feature_description = {
      "token_ids":  tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)
  }

  def parse_proto(proto):
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(proto, feature_description)
    token_ids = example["token_ids"]
    token_ids = tf.sparse.to_dense(token_ids)
    return token_ids

  return ds.map(parse_proto)

def sentence_create_pad_example_fn(pad_len, 
                          pad_id=pad_id, 
                          cls_id=cls_id, 
                          sep_id=sep_id,
                          trim_beginning=True):
  def sentence_pad_example(x):
    seq_len = pad_len - 2
    x = x[-seq_len:] if trim_beginning else x[:seq_len]
    x = tf.pad(x, [[0, seq_len - tf.shape(x)[-1]]], constant_values=pad_id)
    x = tf.concat([[cls_id], x, [sep_id]], axis=-1)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (pad_len,))
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    return  x
  return sentence_pad_example  

def test_sample_seq_len(tok_id):
  return tf.shape(tok_id)[0]


def serialize_sentence(batched_dataset):
      feature = {
          "token_ids": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=batched_dataset))
      }
      proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
      return proto.SerializeToString()


def convert_input_data(sentences):
    tokenized_texts = [tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
    tokenized_texts = tokenized_texts[0]

    MAX_LEN = 128

    input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_texts)
    sentence_tfrecord_file = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, "data", "sentence.tfrecord")
    serialized_sentences = serialize_sentence(input_ids)
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(sentence_tfrecord_file) as writer:    
        writer.write(serialized_sentences)
    ds = sentence_tfrecord_to_dataset([sentence_tfrecord_file])
    ds = ds.map(sentence_create_pad_example_fn(pad_len=max_seq_len))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)
    return ds
```

[Update] This error is relevant to the "ds = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)". It has the same shape, but internal data of this FetchedDataset becomes None... Is there anyone could explain why this code drop the internal data? If it is related to drop_remainder, I changed it to False, but its shape is not matched with model...
I'm really appreciate your any comments

[Update]
When I changed 'ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)' into  'ds.batch(batch_size)' there is a data but the shape is become (1,512)
The error message is changed as follows:
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_predict_function_238864}} Compilation failure: Input to reshape is a tensor with 786432 values, but the requested shape has 6291456
[[{{node sequential_1/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/key/Tensordot/Reshape}}]]
TPU compilation failed
[[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_16383985289316826946/_4]]

Comment: From the code it means that one of either `total_epochs` or  `self._inferred_steps` is a None type object, basically means you've not inputted it. This mostly happens when you've forgotten to tell the code some parameter settings. Need more information to see which one you've forgotten.

Comment: @ZWang Thank you for your response. I looked through the code and couldn't find the self._inferred_steps variable. I think it is internal variable in the data_adapter.py. To give you more information, I attached the link of my whole code. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BeG1n9IJmoxBZ2FicKKqWTdQ11jfYxlC?usp=sharing. I really appreciate your kindness

Comment: If that's the case, check compatibility (if you have the correct Keras version for the code) because they might have changed it at a earlier/later date

Comment: @ZWang I ran this code in google collab. Is it possible to get a problem issue? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possibly, you still need to check the keras/tensorflow versions to make sure they are compatible though.

Comment: @ZWang I checked the version of keras and tensorflow. My keras version is 2.3.1, tensorflow version is 2.2.0. The latest version of keras is 2.4.0 so I upgraded the keras version into 2.4.0 but, the error message still remained same :(. I am really appreciate your help

Comment: I think the current compatibility is keras 2.3.1 with tensorflow 2.2.0 and python 3.7

Comment: Upload your code to github and I'll take a look  EDIT: just saw it's on google I'll look there EDIT2: Where do you call the model.predict() function in your code? I can't find it

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I call the model predict() in the last part of code. Here is the code, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BeG1n9IJmoxBZ2FicKKqWTdQ11jfYxlC?usp=sharing.

Comment: So I did some digging into the tensorflow engine code, seems that the error you get is only an error message but it's indicative of a deeper problem somewhere else in the code. Since you are running only `model.predict() `, I would guess one of three things is causing your problem. You've not loaded the model properly (loading then compiling) , not loaded the data properly (my guess) or not running the model properly (you need to add a batch_size to the `model.predict()` function)

Comment: @ZWang I tried to input batch_size in model.predict() and changed it value but it didn't work. I think your guess is correct, when I print the PrefetchDataset shapes: (128, 512), types: tf.float32, internal data is nothing. Because of there is no data Out of Range error happen first. But I couldn't understand why this code "dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)" drop the internal data... Thank you for your time and efforts.